# DOM - Determine strpos in original html for element

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I am using PHP/DOM to parse an HTML document.  Then using regular expressions to locate certain content within certain elements.  For a number of reasons, I would rather apply the regular expressions to the entire html string and record their string positions.  Then when parsing the HTML with DOM check the elements string position to know if it had a "hit".

So the specific question is: If I have a DOM element, how do I find the position it is in the orignal HTML string?

Comment: not easily. what's in ram inside the DOM object doesn't necessarily correspond 1:1 with what's in the "raw" html. e.g. bad/malformed html may get cleaned up as best as the DOM parser can figure it out.